# ListView in Fragment not saving scroll position on popBackStack

Tags: android

I have a listview in a fragment.  When I scroll down a few items, then select an item, I put a new fragment on the screen with this code:

```
    MyNewFragment fragment = MyNewFragment.newInstance();
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(FRAGMENT_ID, fragment);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
```

Then when I hit the back key and go to the first fragment, my listview doesn't save its Y location.  I've tried implementing onSaveInstance(), but it doesn't get called when the new fragment is displayed using the above code.  I am using the support fragment manager class.  What am I doing wrong?